# Using Beautiful soup I want to find siblings of p having a certain text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Right now I am using the following code:

```
containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'a')
```

and then I am using an if statement as below:

```
if containers[i].p.text == 'text':
```

but it is taking a lot of time.

My question is can I make a modification at the first line of code to make it faster. I want to find the siblings of the paragraph containing a certain text.
Basically the paragraph is a child of div

Comment: You could use a lambda in find_all but that might be even slower

Comment: Try to update with some elements and point out which ones you wanna parse from that and where you are going wrong?

Comment: @Shahin I am not going wrong anywhere. I just want to make it faster

Comment: So, you think you have provided sufficient information and resources to get an efficient solution. Ain't it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function to `find_all` that checks if text, tag, and parent tag matches.

```
def find_siblings_for_element_with_text(html_soup, text, tag='p', parent_tag='div'):
    result_set = html_soup.find_all(
        lambda el: (
            el.text == text
            and el.name.lower() == tag
            and el.parent.name == parent_tag)
    )

    return [
        list(el.previous_siblings) + list(el.next_siblings)
        for el in result_set
    ]

find_siblings_for_element_with_text(html_soup, 'text')
```

Comment: As @t.m.adam pointed out, it might be even slower. You can benchmark this against your current implementation. I'll be interested to know what the results are